# Mootools equivalent of jQuery toggle()?

Tags: jquery, mootools

I'm using trying to use mootools for a quick task of toggling some text on click. But I can't seem to find a Mootools equivalent of jQuery's toggle() function.

What I'm trying to do is as follows:

```
$('a#id').toggle(
 function() {
  $(this).set('html', 'new text');
 },
 function() {
  $(this).set('html', 'old text');
 }
);
```

How would I modify the above code for mootools?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know that "toggle" on mootools doesn't exists.

You could "implement" it, by this way for example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/rdvx8/

Is this what you'd like to obtain?

**Edit** (for mootools developers :D ), this could be a way to create a general "toggle":

```
Element.implement({
    toggle: function(fn1,fn2){
        this.store('toggled',false);
        return this.addEvent('click',function(event){
            event.stop();
             if(this.retrieve('toggled')){
                 fn1.call(this);
             }else{
                 fn2.call(this);
             }
            this.store('toggled',!(this.retrieve('toggled')));
        });
    }
});

//using it in a 'jQuery' mode

$('mya').toggle(
   function() {
      this.set('html', 'new text');
   },
   function() {
      this.set('html', 'old text');
   }
);
```

fiddle here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/qBZ47/

**edit 2** check out an improved version http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/UZRx5/ (thanks [@Dimitar Christoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126998/dimitar-christoff))

Comment: @Probocop you're welcome! P.s. take a look at the updated answer to see a 'general' toggle extension ;)

Comment: +1 - make sure you `return this` from element prototype so you don't break chaining :) another improvement would be to save the click callback in element storage or closure with some second method - so it can be removed by a precise match of `"click", element.retrieve("toggler");` - unless you don't plan on stopping toggling. :)

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff : I did set the return (as you can see, my updated version is older than your comment :D ), but I wasn't able to update JSFiddle.. I clicked update->then->set As Base ..but the base version still remained the same.. btw, no prob.. :D thanks for your suggestions :). Just a question: storing that click callback could improve the 'mootoggle' just in the case I want to be able to stop toggling?

Comment: tbh, i'd use a closure for that and not public element storage (see my reply) - accessing a variable is faster than an element prototype "retrieve" which then does more lookups of objects and object properties to get the data (even so, element storage is FAST).

Comment: Oh, one thing you can do to improve it - i would not stop the event (that should happen downstream at callback functions) - rather, pass the event as an argument to the callback functions instead. Then it's going to be perfect.

Comment: sorry, fixed it again - http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/qBZ47/5/ - now it supports unlimited functions via `arguments`. not that you'd use it but you never know... better to be able to :)`

Answer (score 5):

i know you accepted the other answer but mootools 1.3 now provides an excellent new feature, Element Pseudos which I feel will be a good solution here. for starters, code below

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/VR9k8/4/

```
(function() {
    var toggled = 0;
    Event.definePseudo('toggle', function(split, funcsArray, args){
         if (funcsArray.length && funcsArray[toggled])
             funcsArray[toggled].apply(this, args); // args[0] is the Event instance

         toggled++;
         if (toggled >= funcsArray.length)
             toggled = 0;
     });
})();

document.id("foo").addEvent("click:toggle", [function(e) {
    e.stop();
    alert("function 1");
}, function(e) {
    e.stop();
    alert("function 2");
}, function(e) {
    e.stop();
    // event object (args[0])
    console.dir(e);
    alert("function 3");
}]);
```

...will allow you to daisy chain nn number of functions to loop-run consecutively as well as passing on arguments or at least the original event.

docs: http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Event.Pseudos

the equivalent or improved version of the element prototype solution is [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/qBZ47/4/)

Comment: Very very good Dimitar :) I didn't think about pseudo..Btw I think my solution for this particular case could me more 'compatible'.. +1 obv ;) ..just a curiosity: are you into the core/more team?

Comment: Yes, your solution gives them familiar syntax and does not need mootools 1.3 or mootools-more so that's very true. I only offered mine as an alternative POV that is slightly more interesting (because it's still new!). The only core team member that lurks here is Arian, alas, I am nowt but a fanboi that tags along at their IRC, local meetups and hackathlons. :) Have had little to contribute, aside from reporting bugs / sample fixes and having a go at making some of the demos for 1.3 (which I have yet to push on github). That + the blog, that is. Anything helps, right? :)