# mootools toggle button problem

Tags: javascript, mootools, thumbnails, togglebutton

I'm trying to code a function that let me toggle in and out all thumbnails in a list depending on their classes.
e.g., if I click "print" on my menu bar, I need all thumbs with the "print" class to be hidden. If I click it a second time, the hidden thumbs are showing up.

Here is what I came up with :

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
       $$('.menu_button').toggle(
        function() {
            this.fade(0.5);
            var buttonId = this.id;
            $('slider_list').getElements('.'+buttonId).each(function(li) {
                li.tween('width','0');
            });
        },
        function() {
            this.fade(1);
            var buttonId = this.id;
            $('slider_list').getElements('.'+buttonId).each(function(li) {
                li.tween('width','100');
            });
        }
    );  

});



//toggle (emulate JQuery's toggle)
(function() {
    var toggled = 0;
    Element.implement({
        toggle: function(fn1, fn2) {
            var fns = [fn1, fn2];
            return this.addEvent('click', function(){
                fns[toggled].apply(this, arguments);
                toggled = toggled == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

I've found the toggle function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748436/mootools-equivalent-of-jquery-toggle)

Now I experience some issues. 
First no matter what I do there will always be a thumb left at the end of the list. 
Then some clicks on the menu won't do anything. Generally when I click on a button in a different state (hidden/shown) than the previous one, there will always be a null click...

Anybody ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented it in a way that allows multiple functions, although not at all MooTools like, it will work. The problem with the code you are using is that each element which uses toggle is toggling the same `toggled` variable

```
Element.implement({
    toggle: function() {
       this.store('toggle_options', {
         fn: arguments,
         cur: 0
       });
       this.addEvent('click', function(e) {
           e.stop();
           var opts = this.retrieve('toggle_options');
           console.log(opts.fn.length, opts.cur);
           opts.fn[opts.cur++].apply(this);
           if(opts.cur >= opts.fn.length) opts.cur = 0;
       }); 
    } 
});

$('button').toggle(
    function() {
      this.set('text', 'foo 1');  
    },
    function() {
      this.set('text', 'bar 2');
    }
);
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/94FFj/

Although I would recommend you implemented your code as this:

```
  $$('.menu_button').each(function(button) {
    button.store('toggle_active', 0);
    button.addEvent('click', function(e) {
      e.stop();
      var active = this.retrieve('toggle_active');
      var opts = [{opacity: 1, width: 0}, {opacity: 0.5, width: 100}];
      this.fade(opts[active].opacity);
      $$('slider_list .' + this.get('id')).tween('width', opts[active].width);
      this.store('toggle_active', active ? 0 : 1);
    });
  })
```

Comment: alright first thx for your answer.

Your toggle function alone resolved the null click but your implementation of my function created a new one : this time the first click on each menu button is null. Then it works.
So I'll just keep the toggle one.

Now unfortunatly it doesn't change anything regarding the last thumb refusing to be toggled out. 

I don't understand every part of your code so I can't really correct this.

Comment: if the `$().toggle` function is the one that doesn't work on first click, you may try inverting the order of the functions you pass into it, for ex: `$('button').toggle(f1, f2)` to `$('button').toggle(f2, f1)`

Comment: no the second code adds the null click. it works fine with the basic implementation.